# Reading *.cdf files in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, netcdf, arctoolbox, files

I received some geospatial data (on rainfall) in a "cdf" format.

I have worked with "nc" files and uses the 'Make NetCDF Raster Layer' tool in ArcMap to read NetCDF files.

However, I wasn't able to use it to read the file with .cdf extension.

Is there an alternative way to read such files?

I have access to ArcMap, QGIS and Python so if there's a solution using any of these tools please let me know.

Comment: Providing a list of products changes the ArcGIS-titled question into multiple questions (which violates the one question per Question  policy). Please **edit** the question to contain more details about what you attempted and the exact errors that resulted from those attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI developed a Multidimension Supplemental toolbox which you could download [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9f963f362fe5417f87d44618796db938). There are several tools dealing with cdf format.

The tools are:

1. Describe Multidimensional Dataset
2. Make NetCDF Regular Points Layer
3. Make NetCDF Station Points Layer
4. Make NetCDF Trajectory Points Layer
5. OPeNDAP to NetCDF
6. Get Variable Statistics
7. Get Variable Statistics Over Dimension
8. Multidimensional Zonal Statistics
9. Multidimensional Zonal Statistics As Table

Answer (score 1):

you could try changing the file extension to.nc. The format of the files basically the same, [as the software doesn't use file extensions](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html), and this has been recommended to users of other software [here](http://www.pmel.noaa.gov/maillists/tmap/ferret_users/fu_2003/msg00618.html) and [here](http://gradsusr.org/pipermail/gradsusr/2010-January/010149.html).