# Converting CDF file to NetCDF file to use in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, netcdf

This is a GIS question as well as a Remote Sensing question.
I have downloaded CDF files from the ESA from MyEarth online and want to use them in ArcMap. In ArcMap you can Make NetCDF a Raster Layer. Is there some way I can convert CDF to NetCDF? Or do I need to? Should a CDF file work here?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181668/reading-cdf-files-in-arcmap